# Filenot found error when i run with site guest user license on the debug log

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

We have a force.com site which we are in the build process. When i run the home page of the force.com site and click on a button to go to my visual force pages, i am getting a file not found error on the debug log. I turned on debug log for the guest site user license for my site and i am not getting any debug outputs at all. My site is here
http://peakdevint.devint.cs15.force.com/ I have attached a screen shot of the issue.Could you guys let me know what could be the reason for this and how do i get my debug output for the log?
[image]

Comment: +1 for including the _actual_ site URL in your question, it helps!

Answer (score 2):

There are two assets on your site which don't exist. When these assets are requested, Salesforce serves `FileNotFound.page` as a response (hence filling up your Debug Logs).

1. http://peakdevint.devint.cs15.force.com/css/application.css

   Line 15: `<link href="css/application.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`
2. http://peakdevint.devint.cs15.force.com/js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js

   Line 17: `<script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js" type="text/javascript">`

I can see your `application.css` stylesheet is included correctly from the `PEAKStyles` static resource, so you can hunt down the runaway `link` element and delete that from the page / template. As for `modernizr-2.0.6.min.js`, you can probably delete that `script` tag too if it's not used ;-)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your quick reply. Can you tell me how you found the the filenotfound errors on the page? What tool did you use to find it and how can i find it myself?